# Multiple multivariate timeseries supervised anomalies prediction

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, knn, anomaly-detection

I have multiple timeseries datasets. Each dataset represents a manufacturing process, has 36000 rows and 4 columns, is labeled, and some of them contain anomalies. There is:

- A *Timestamp* index (values are recorded each second for 10h), this index is basically the same for every dataset.
- 2 features: *Flow* and *Pressure*, which are partly correlated (and i'd like to take this information into account if possible)
- 2 labels: *Flow anomaly* and *Pressure anomaly*. They = 1 if value is an anomaly, 0 if not.

I want to train a machine learning model to **identify anomalies** on other timeseries data of the same kind. I'd also like to **predict anomalies**. I'd like to train an **Isolation Forest** model, or a KNN or neural network amongst others.

But I am having trouble handling multiple multivariate and multi-label timeseries data.

I tried a library called Darts in python, made to handle this kind of problem, but I don't know how to train an Isolation Forest model on multivariate timeseries using this library, and I don't find it on the documentation.

My data is stored in csv files that I import as pandas dataframes. I use Pyhton 3.11.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very general question and it is related more to research of what is the best and how to do it.

First of all, `Darts` is great for time-series tasks, but it doesn't include Isolation Forest. `scikit-learn` on the other hand does so you need to use both.

Below is a toy example to illustrate this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, f1_score

# fake data
np.random.seed(0)

# fake timestamps
timestamps = pd.date_range(start='2023-08-01', periods=36000, freq='1S')

# fake Flow and Pressure
data1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Timestamp': timestamps,
    'Flow': np.random.normal(100, 10, 36000),
    'Pressure': np.random.normal(50, 5, 36000),
    'Flow anomaly': np.random.randint(0, 2, 36000),
    'Pressure anomaly': np.random.randint(0, 2, 36000),
})

data2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Timestamp': timestamps,
    'Flow': np.random.normal(90, 8, 36000),
    'Pressure': np.random.normal(55, 6, 36000),
    'Flow anomaly': np.random.randint(0, 2, 36000),
    'Pressure anomaly': np.random.randint(0, 2, 36000),
})

data3 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Timestamp': timestamps,
    'Flow': np.random.normal(110, 12, 36000),
    'Pressure': np.random.normal(45, 4, 36000),
    'Flow anomaly': np.random.randint(0, 2, 36000),
    'Pressure anomaly': np.random.randint(0, 2, 36000),
})

# Concatenate all datasets
combined_data = pd.concat([data1, data2, data3], ignore_index=True)
combined_data['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(combined_data['Timestamp'])
combined_data.set_index('Timestamp', inplace=True)


# split features and targets
features = combined_data[['Flow', 'Pressure']]
labels = combined_data[['Flow anomaly', 'Pressure anomaly']]

# Split into train and test sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, labels, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

# Scaling
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test)

# model fitting
isolation_forest_flow = IsolationForest()
isolation_forest_pressure = IsolationForest()

isolation_forest_flow.fit(X_train_scaled)
isolation_forest_pressure.fit(X_train_scaled)

# predict the test set
pred_flow = isolation_forest_flow.predict(X_test_scaled)
pred_pressure = isolation_forest_pressure.predict(X_test_scaled)

# predictions back to labels (0 == inliers, 1 == anomalies)
pred_flow_labels = np.where(pred_flow == -1, 1, 0)
pred_pressure_labels = np.where(pred_pressure == -1, 1, 0)

# accuracy
accuracy_flow = accuracy_score(y_test['Flow anomaly'], pred_flow_labels)
accuracy_pressure = accuracy_score(y_test['Pressure anomaly'], pred_pressure_labels)


print(f"Flow Accuracy: {accuracy_flow}")
print(f"Pressure Accuracy: {accuracy_pressure}")
```

The above prints:

```
Flow Accuracy: 0.4999537037037037 
Pressure Accuracy:0.4988888888888889
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is very helpful. Do you know is there is a way to take into account the correlation between the Pressure and Flow variables please?

Comment: This is a bit more tricky. In what sense to take the correlation into account?

Comment: This data is about water flow during a big manufacturing process. If the Pressure increases, then the Flow should also increase (they are somewhat proportional). An anomaly consists in something blocking the water flow inside the pipes, which is not good. If this happens, the flow decreases, and we need more pressure to unclog the pipes, so Pressure increases right after.

Comment: If there are very higly correlated then you can use one only and one isolationforest. the forest returns the anomaly score of each sample using the IsolationForest algorithm. Please accept my answer if it helped